# counter name for NewTasks environment

Tags: counters, exsheets, tasks

I'm using `tasks` (as a subset of `exsheets`) to create environments `exer2` and `exer3` which organize exercise sets in a calculus workbook into rows and columnns. I am also using the `exsheets` environments `question` and `solution` to keep track of the solutions and print them up in an orderly fashion.

I know that the name of the first level {enumerate} counter is `enumi` as shown in line 9 of the preamble. What I do not know is the name of the counter in the environments created by `tasks`. When I use the syntax suggested in section 7.6, pp 13-14 of the `exsheets` manual, I get a text echo "tsk[a]", not the counter.

I can handle the final formatting of the labels in `solutions`, I just need to know how to get the "a, b, c" instead of "1 tsk[a], 1 tsk[a], 1 tsk[a]".

What am I missing here?

[Included below: TeX code in its entirety, output from MS Word to show what I want and what I'm getting from LaTeX]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn,titlepage,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[left=.75in, right=.75in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{exsheets} 
\SetupExSheets[question]{pre-hook=\vspace{-24pt},post-hook=\vspace{-12pt},headings=block}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{headings=runin}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=\arabic{enumi}~tsk[a]}
% ENVIRONMENTS FOR EXERCISES USING TASKS
\NewTasks[before-skip=6pt,after-skip=6pt,after-item-skip=0pt,item-indent=24pt,label-width=6pt,label-offset=12pt,counter-format=tsk[a].~]{exer3}[\exercise](3)
\NewTasks[before-skip=6pt,after-skip=6pt,after-item-skip=0pt,item-indent=24pt,label-width=6pt,label-offset=12pt,counter-format=tsk[a].~]{exer2}[\exercise](2)

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item First exercise set. 
        \begin{exer3} 
        \exercise % THIS IS THE COUNTER WHOSE NAME I WANT
            \begin{question}
                Set one exercise one
            \end{question}
            \begin{solution}
                Set one solution one\\
                 \hrule \vspace{6pt}
             \end{solution}
        \exercise
            \begin{question}
                Set one exercise two
            \end{question}
            \begin{solution}
                Set one solution two\\
                \hrule \vspace{6pt}
            \end{solution}
        \exercise
            \begin{question}
                Set one exercise three
            \end{question}
            \begin{solution}
                Set one solution three\\
                \hrule \vspace{6pt}
            \end{solution}
            \end{exer3}
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item Second exercise set.
            \begin{exer2}
        \exercise
            \begin{question}
                Set two exercise one
            \end{question}
            \begin{solution}
                Set two solution one\\
                \hrule \vspace{6pt}
            \end{solution}
        \exercise
             \begin{question}
                Set two exercise two
            \end{question}
            \begin{solution}
                Set two solution two\\
                \hrule \vspace{6pt}
            \end{solution}
            \end{exer2}
    \end{enumerate}

\hrule \vspace{2pt} \hrule \vspace{6pt}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

---

What I want:

```
1a. Set one solution one
________________________________________
1b. Set one solution two
________________________________________
1b. Set one solution three
________________________________________
2a. Set two solution one
________________________________________
2b. Set two solution two
________________________________________
```

---

What I get:

```
Solution 1 tsk[a]   Set one solution one
________________________________________
Solution 1 tsk[a]   Set one solution two
________________________________________
Solution 1 tsk[a]   Set one solution three
________________________________________
Solution 2 tsk[a]   Set two solution one
________________________________________
Solution 2 tsk[a]   Set two solution two
________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `tasks` in a way I never imagined…

You have to make the `tasks` counter (which actually is an internal expl3 integer) known to `exsheets` pattern reader:

```
\usepackage{exsheets,tasks}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \AddCounterPattern* [exsheets] {task} {tsk}
  \ReadCounterFrom    [exsheets] {task} \g__tasks_int
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Embedded in your example document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{exsheets,tasks}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \AddCounterPattern*[exsheets]{task}{tsk}
  \ReadCounterFrom   [exsheets]{task}\g__tasks_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\SetupExSheets{
  question/pre-hook = \vspace{-24pt},
  question/post-hook = \vspace{-12pt},
  question/headings = block ,
  solution/headings = runin ,
  solution/post-hook = \par \hrule \vspace{6pt} ,
  counter-format=\arabic{enumi}~tsk[a]
}

\NewTasks[
  before-skip=6pt,
  after-skip=6pt,
  after-item-skip=0pt,
  item-indent=24pt,
  label-width=6pt,
  label-offset=12pt,
  counter-format=tsk[a].~]{exer3}[\exercise](3)
\NewTasks[
  before-skip=6pt,
  after-skip=6pt,
  after-item-skip=0pt,
  item-indent=24pt,
  label-width=6pt,
  label-offset=12pt,
  counter-format=tsk[a].~]{exer2}[\exercise](2)

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First exercise set. 
  \begin{exer3} 
    \exercise
    \begin{question}
      Set one exercise one
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
      Set one solution one
    \end{solution}
    \exercise
    \begin{question}
      Set one exercise two
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
      Set one solution two
    \end{solution}
    \exercise
    \begin{question}
      Set one exercise three
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
      Set one solution three
    \end{solution}
  \end{exer3}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Second exercise set.
  \begin{exer2} 
    \exercise
    \begin{question}
      Set two exercise one
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
      Set two solution one
    \end{solution}
    \exercise
    \begin{question}
      Set two exercise two
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
      Set two solution two
    \end{solution}
  \end{exer2}
\end{enumerate}

\hrule \vspace{2pt} \hrule \vspace{6pt}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: @user114366 Where did you fail? I added a modified version of your example to my answer to show you that it's easy

Comment: I thought that I typed it identically to what you gave me (with the spaces) and the compiler returned an undefined control sequence error for the \end{exer3} line with a reference to g_. So I copied and pasted what you gave me and it worked. Now I see the double underbar between g and tasks. Well, duh. I NEVER would have figured this one out on my own.

Comment: Now, by using `headings=runin-nr' with what you gave me, I've almost got what I want. Is there an easy way to get the label "3.c" to not be boldface? Or should I open a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get that to work, but I did figure out a different answer after reading some other posts on the forum

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{exer2}{\setcounter{question}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{exer3}{\setcounter{question}{0}}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=\arabic{enumi}.\alph{question}}
```

appears to be working.